# Where to ask about processing power of top cloud services and supercomputers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a 2-3 questions concerning processing power of top cloud services and supercomputers, like:

- What is an approximate processing power of top five cloud services?
- What is a total processing power of all top ten supercomputers?
- (*or maybe in general*) What is an approximate processing power of nowadays world?

What site would be best for this purpose:

- Super User,
- Web Applications,
- *other*,
- *none* (off-topic across entire SE).

Comment: That hardly seems a practical question that would attract answers with lasting value. Based on that I would say no site in the SE network is suited for that.

Comment: As there are existing sites dedicated to this, I'd suggest using them.

Comment: Trivia questions are generally off topic everywhere. These questions aren't really answers to practical issues you face, a generally network-wide requirement (generally speaking in a general sense of the word general).

Comment: @RoryAlsop Can you provide any example of such?

Comment: using only your search terms in Google gives me the definitive lists including the TOP500 list on Wikipedia

Comment: @RoryAlsop It seems, we misunderstand each other. I have already used Google and got the information about TOP500. But this is a list of super-computers, while I'm seeking for a source of information about cloud services' computing power. I.e. How many processors, disks, RAM etc. Google Cloud, Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure etc. has.

Comment: Worth editing your question to state that it isn't about supercomputers then... As regards the cloud providers, there would be no real numbers - they change continually. Look at eg Google's replace numbers on faulty drives, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say None and that such questions would be off-topic on all SE sites.

As soon as you ask a question that seeks to elicit multiple answers to guide your choice of technology, I think you are into the realm of needing a recommendation site, but SE has only two of these (Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations) and I think your questions may not meet their strict asking guidelines.